Wiring the output of a D flip-flop to its input
I've got a simple question about flip-flops, particularly the SN74LS175.
I want to know if it's possible to wire the output of the flip-flop through some combinatorial circuit and then back into the input of the same flip flop, so that on the next clock pulse the new input gets latched correctly. (An example of such a circuit might be the next-state logic of a state machine).
I've tried it out on a breadboard and it seems to work fine, but I am confused about the setup time and the data hold time, if changing the output data on a new clock (thus changing the input data via the combinatorial circuit) will cause timing issues.
Just wanted to know if this is accepted as fine practice for these sort of chips, or it timing and stability will be a concern.

The hold time is 0ns (noted to be under nominal conditions 5V / 25°C, a hint that you might have to allow a bit more under worst-case Vcc and temperature conditions).
So your logic circuit can't possibly violate the hold-time specification if it's strictly based on the FF outputs.
The output has some propagation delay (no minimum specified, but it's certainly a few ns). Worst case would be when you connect /Q to D to get it to toggle.
For example, here is another FF (74VHC74) which has a minimum hold time of 500ps and a minimum propagation delay of 1ns. So a direct connection is legit. Since the one you are considering has a 0ns hold time, the minimum prop delay is not as important. Some actually have a negative minimum hold time, so a bit more margin (provided you avoid thiotimoline wiring).
This assumes sharp clock signals, clean Vcc etc. If you've got funky stuff going on then all bets are off.

Yes, it is definitely possible.
It will work as long as the data setup and data hold times and propagation delays in the logic are taken into account.
For example wiring the inverted output directly into data input makes a clock divider.

Some elementary transformations of the D-type FF obtained using the characteristic equations of each. Each gate introduces a delay in the switching times:


The general idea is that whatever combinatorial logic is in the feedback path from the FF output to input propagates much slower than the input hold time of the FF. In TTL, ECL and most any CMOS logic family, the propagation time of a single inverter will vastly exceed the minimum hold time needed on the input of a FF.
So, your question comes from a very reasonable concern, and it's good that you thought about it. In most cases, in practice, it's not a problem.
In the most basic relay-based latch, the minimum input hold time depends on the relative electromechanical inertias of the relays used. The minimum hold time is zero (actually negative) as long as the mux relay (RLY1) is quite a bit faster than the memory element relay (RLY2):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If it is desired to use identical relays, then an extra relay is needed to provide the extended hold without depending on the input:

simulate this circuit
The latch above is still subject to output glitches if the enable pulse is too short, of course. This can be fixed at the cost of added latency by taking the output from the delay element RLY3:

simulate this circuit
